# Problem with reading file...while (!feof(file)) leads to infinite loop!

Tags: file, fopen, feof

```
void OpenFile() {

    FILE *fp;

    char buffer[1024];
    int number;
    fp=fopen("godess.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {  
            while (!feof(fp)) {
                printf("In loop!!!!");
                fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&number);
            }
            fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Hello...I'm trying to read a file ...but in the line where I write " while (!feof(fp))"....it leads in an infinite loop....can anyone please help me to solve this matter..Please I have tried everything...but nothing happens!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: Also: `if( fp == NULL ) { perror( "godess.txt" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 2):

You should check the return value of fscanf to see whether it has successfully read a number.